How in editor with tabs get currenct model?
In a Laravel 10 / Nova 4.27 app, I'm using a large editor with tabs ("eminiarts/nova-tabs": "^2.2"), and I need to show or hide one of the tabs based on the value of the other_shipping field. Additionally, I want to set the header text and background color depending on the current status of the opened order.
Here's what I've tried:
public function fields(NovaRequest $request) {
    $isEdit = ! empty($this->id);
    \Log::info(' -13 fields $isEdit::');
    \Log::info(json_encode($isEdit));
    $editorTitle = 'Select status manually';
    $headingBgColor = 'text-white-100';
    
    $otherShipping= false;
    $status = null;
    if ($isEdit) {
        $otherShipping = (bool) $this->other_shipping?->value;
        $status = $this->status;
    }
    
    \Log::info(' -145 $status::');
    \Log::info(json_encode($status));
    $statusOptions = OrderStatusEnum::getStatusSelectionItems();
    if ($isEdit) {
        $headingBgColor = OrderStatusEnum::getStatusColors(hexValue: false)[$status->value];
        $editorTitle = ' With "'.OrderStatusEnum::getLabel($this->status).'" status use buttons to change status';
   }
    
   return [
        Heading::make('<p class="text-xl font-bold ' . $headingBgColor . '">' . $editorTitle . '</p>')->asHtml(),
        Tabs::make('Order editor', [
            Tab::make('Details', [
                BelongsTo::make('Creator', 'creator', User::class),
                // ...
            ]),
            Tab::make('Billing Information', $this->getBillingFields())->showIf($otherShipping),
            // ...
        ]),
    ];

However, this isn't working as expected. I need to check if the page is in index, updating, creating, or detail mode. How can I do this? Also, how can I access the model in updating and detail modes?

This is a loaded question! Start by fixing the isEdit logic using the NovaRequest to properly detect if you’re in update or detail mode:
$isEdit = $request->isUpdateOrUpdateAttachedRequest() || $request->isResourceDetailRequest();


Could, you please, give link for docs of these (and similar methods) ? I did not find a lot at https://nova.laravel.com/

also, please, hint how to get current model in fields mathod in edit mode( $request->isUpdateOrUpdateAttachedRequest() === TRUE )

Currently, this isnt in Laravel Nova's official documentation. I look through the source code to find these methods. Look at the NovaRequest you will find many hidden features.
